# How can I parse a Wikipedia XML dump with Python?

Tags: python, xpath, elementtree

I have:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


def strip_tag_name(t):
    t = elem.tag
    idx = k = t.rfind("}")
    if idx != -1:
        t = t[idx + 1:]
    return t


events = ("start", "end")

title = None
for event, elem in ET.iterparse('data/enwiki-20190620-pages-articles-multistream.xml', events=events):
    tname = strip_tag_name(elem.tag)

    if event == 'end':
        if tname == 'title':
            title = elem.text
        elif tname == 'page':
            print(title, elem.text)
```

This seems to give the title just fine, but the page `text` always seems blank. What am I missing?

I haven't been able to open the file (it's huge), but I think this is an accurate snippet:

```
<mediawiki xmlns="http://www.mediawiki.org/xml/export-0.10/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mediawiki.org/xml/export-0.10/ http://www.mediawiki.org/xml/export-0.10.xsd" version="0.10" xml:lang="en">
  <siteinfo>
    <sitename>Wikipedia</sitename>
    <dbname>enwiki</dbname>
    <base>https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page</base>
    <generator>MediaWiki 1.29.0-wmf.12</generator>
    <case>first-letter</case>
    <namespaces>
      ...
    </namespaces>
  </siteinfo>
  <page>
    <title>AccessibleComputing</title>
    <ns>0</ns>
    <id>10</id>
    <redirect title="Computer accessibility" />
    <revision>
      <id>631144794</id>
      <parentid>381202555</parentid>
      <timestamp>2014-10-26T04:50:23Z</timestamp>
      <contributor>
        <username>Paine Ellsworth</username>
        <id>9092818</id>
      </contributor>
      <comment>add [[WP:RCAT|rcat]]s</comment>
      <model>wikitext</model>
      <format>text/x-wiki</format>
      <text xml:space="preserve">#REDIRECT [[Computer accessibility]]

\{\{Redr|move|from CamelCase|up\}\}</text>
      <sha1>4ro7vvppa5kmm0o1egfjztzcwd0vabw</sha1>
    </revision>
  </page>
  <page>
    <title>Anarchism</title>
    <ns>0</ns>
    <id>12</id>
    <revision>
      <id>766348469</id>
      <parentid>766047928</parentid>
      <timestamp>2017-02-19T18:08:07Z</timestamp>
      <contributor>
        <username>GreenC bot</username>
        <id>27823944</id>
      </contributor>
      <minor />
      <comment>Reformat 1 archive link. [[User:Green Cardamom/WaybackMedic_2.1|Wayback Medic 2.1]]</comment>
      <model>wikitext</model>
      <format>text/x-wiki</format>
      <text xml:space="preserve">
      ...
      </text>
    </revision>
  </page>
</mediawiki>
```

Comment: parsing is probably wrong somewhere with respect to the tags, share a snippet of the XML for people to see

Comment: Done - shared an XML snippet

Comment: Your snippet will not parse.

Comment: The text content of the `<page>` element is just whitespace. I suppose you want the text of the `<text>` element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text refers to the text between the element tags (i.e. `<tag>text</tag>`) and not to all the child elements. Thus, in case of the `title` element one has:

```
<title>AccessibleComputing</title>
```

and the text between the tags is `AccessibleComputing`.

In the case of the `page` element, the only text defined is `'\n    '` and there are other child elements (see below), including the `title` element:

```
<page>
    <title>Anarchism</title>
    <ns>0</ns>
    <id>12</id>
    ... 
</page>
```

See more details in [w3schools page](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_elements.asp)

If you want to parse the file, I would recomend to use either `findall` method:

```
from lxml import etree
from lxml.etree import tostring

tree = etree.parse('data/enwiki-20190620-pages-articles-multistream.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
# iterate through all the titles
for title in root.findall(".//title", namespaces=root.nsmap):
    print(tostring(title))
    print(title.text)
```

which generates this output:

```
b'<title xmlns="http://www.mediawiki.org/xml/export-0.10/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">AccessibleComputing</title>\n    '
AccessibleComputing
b'<title xmlns="http://www.mediawiki.org/xml/export-0.10/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">Anarchism</title>\n    '
Anarchism
```

or the [`xpath`](https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html) method:

```
nsmap = root.nsmap
nsmap['x'] = root.nsmap[None]
nsmap.pop(None)
# iterate through all the pages
for page in root.findall(".//x:page", namespaces=nsmap):
    print(page)
    print(repr(page.text)) # which prints '\n    '
    print('number of children: %i' % len(page.getchildren()))
```

and the output is:

```
<Element {http://www.mediawiki.org/xml/export-0.10/}page at 0x7ff75cc610c8>
'\n    '
number of children: 5
<Element {http://www.mediawiki.org/xml/export-0.10/}page at 0x7ff75cc71bc8>
'\n    '
number of children: 5
```

Please see [lxml tutorial](https://lxml.de/2.2/tutorial.html) for more details.

Answer (score 14):

The best approach is to use a the [MWXML](https://github.com/mediawiki-utilities/python-mwxml) python package which is part of the [Mediawiki Utilities](https://github.com/mediawiki-utilities/) (installable with `pip3 install mwxml`). MWXML is designed to solve this specific problem and is widely used. The software was created by research staff at the [Wikimedia Foundation](https://wikimediafoundation.org) and is maintained by a set of researchers inside and outside of the foundation.

Here's a code example adapted from [an example notebook distributed with the library](https://github.com/mediawiki-utilities/python-mwxml/blob/master/ipython/labs_example.ipynb) that prints out page IDs, revision IDs, timestamp, and the length of the text:

```py
import mwxml
import glob

paths = glob.glob('/public/dumps/public/nlwiki/20151202/nlwiki-20151202-pages-meta-history*.xml*.bz2')

def process_dump(dump, path):
  for page in dump:
    for revision in page:
        yield page.id, revision.id, revision.timestamp, len(revision.text)

for page_id, rev_id, rev_timestamp, rev_textlength in mwxml.map(process_dump, paths):
    print("\t".join(str(v) for v in [page_id, rev_id, rev_timestamp, rev_textlength]))
```

The [full example](https://github.com/mediawiki-utilities/python-mwxml/blob/master/ipython/labs_example.ipynb) from which this is adapted reports the number of added and removed image links within each revision. It is fully documented but includes only 25 lines of code.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to get the content of the `text` property of the `<page>` element, but that is just whitespace.

To get the `text` of the `<text>` element, just change

```
elif tname == 'page':
```

to

```
elif tname == 'text':
```

Answer (score 2):

For XML parsing I use package `untangle` from PYPI, which presents a complete document view. Then you have:

```
import untangle

doc = untangle.parse('data/enwiki-20190620-pages-articles-multistream.xml')
for page in doc.mediawiki.page:
    print(page.title.cdata)
    for text in page.revision.text:
        print(text.cdata)
```

Comment: I've exported some pages using the page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Export and it worked like a charm.

Comment: This is a good/easy answer that works with the sample data but it's unlikely to work on "real" Mediawiki XML dumps from large wikis which are often many gigabtes (even terrabytes for Wikipedia) in size. The only real solutions in these case involves some sort of stream-based XML-parsing solution.

Answer (score 0):

To get the Wikipedia article, you need to access the content of the `text` property of the `<text>` element, and not the `<page>` element.

Here is the corrected version of your code:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


def strip_tag_name(t):
    t = elem.tag
    idx = k = t.rfind("}")
    if idx != -1:
        t = t[idx + 1:]
    return t


events = ("start", "end")

title = None
for event, elem in ET.iterparse('data/enwiki-20190620-pages-articles-multistream.xml', events=events):
    tname = strip_tag_name(elem.tag)

    if event == 'end':
        if tname == 'title':
            title = elem.text
        elif tname == 'text':
            print(title, elem.text)

    elem.clear()
```

Since the Wikipedia dump is quite large, don't forget the `elem.clear()` at the end of the for loop.

As mentioned in [mzjn answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57399161/4872288) the content of the `text` property of the `<page>` element is just whitespace.