# Get specific data form xml using Elementtree

Tags: python, elementtree

Hi i have a similar xml :

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <env:Header />
    <env:Body>
        <env:Fault>
            <faultcode>env:Server</faultcode>
            <faultstring>JBO-27024: Failed to validate a row with key oracle.jbo.Key[300000013314061 ] in Offer JBO-27024: Failed to validate a row with key oracle.jbo.Key[300000013314064 ] in RevenueEONon si possono aggiungere prodotti su questa Opportunit\xc3\xa0</faultstring>
            <detail>
                <tns:ServiceErrorMessage xmlns:tns="http://xmlns.tom.com/adf/svc/errors/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="tns:ServiceRowValErrorMessage">
                    <tns:code>27024</tns:code>
                    <tns:message>JBO-27024: Failed to validate a row with key oracle.jbo.Key[300000013314061 ] in Offerta_2_c</tns:message>
                    <tns:severity>SEVERITY_ERROR</tns:severity>
                    <tns:detail xsi:type="tns:ServiceRowValErrorMessage">
                        <tns:code>27024</tns:code>
                        <tns:message>JBO-27024: Failed to validate a row with key jbo.Key[300000013314064 ] in RevenueEO</tns:message>
                        <tns:severity>SEVERITY_ERROR</tns:severity>
                        <tns:detail xsi:type="tns:ServiceErrorMessage">
                            <tns:code />
                            <tns:message>Non si possono aggiungere prodotti</tns:message>/*  THIS ROW  */
                            <tns:severity>SEVERITY_ERROR</tns:severity>
                            <tns:exceptionClassName>ValidationException</tns:exceptionClassName>
                        </tns:detail>
                        <tns:exceptionClassName>oracle.jbo.RowValException</tns:exceptionClassName>
                        <tns:objectName>RevenueEO</tns:objectName>
                    </tns:detail>
                    <tns:exceptionClassName>RowValException</tns:exceptionClassName>
                    <tns:objectName>Offer</tns:objectName>
                </tns:ServiceErrorMessage>
            </detail>
        </env:Fault>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

How can I retrieve the string 'Non si possono aggiungere prodotti' from this XML, the problem is that this info is enclosed in a tag `<tns:message>` and in this XML there are many similar tags. How can I deal with the problem using `ElementTree`, for now I have used regex with little results.

Comment: [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please also show what you've tried and what problems did you encounter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I parse a Wikipedia XML dump with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56888333/how-can-i-parse-a-wikipedia-xml-dump-with-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends a bit what you want to do.

First thing would be to get hold of the namespaces. In the example below, I use the first children of the `detail` element to access the dictionary of namespaces (there may be different ways of doing this):

```py
all_ns = root.findall('.//detail')[0].getchildren()[0].nsmap
```

Then I can iterate through all the messages with `tns` namespace using this for loop and get the one you are interested.

```py
for i in root.findall('.//tns:message', namespaces=all_ns):
    if 'Non si' in i.text:
        print(i.text)
```

However, it would be great to understand the reasoning being you choosing that particular line, given that all the other lines in the log file give information about a particular error.

If you just want to get the errors listed in a hierarchical order (i.e. parent > children) , just run:

```py
for i in root.findall('.//tns:message', namespaces=all_ns):
    print(i.text)
```